# Uploading image using Twitter API - java

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, twitter

I want to upload a new profile image using the twitter API ,In the documentation its is mentioned 
 **this method expects raw multipart data, not a URL to an image.**
How do i create such data and pass it to the API ?

Regards,
Abhishek Ranjan

Answer (score -1):

You must a make POST request, using cURL. Or Java equivalent of cURL.